# Set .data segment size in C, dynamically

Tags: c

Is there a means by which to manipulate the .data segment size in C without increasing compile size of the binary (i.e. setting the size without setting any variables within)?

Comment: Impossible to answer without a specific system in mind.

Comment: If your question is about C, then don't tag C++.

Comment: Lundin - are you claiming this is architecture dependant or compiler dependant?

Comment: It's not clear what is the end goalhere. How is the space going to be used ?

Comment: Indeed, it's architecture/compiler dependent whether such a thing as "segments" even exists.  Certainly the C standard has no concept of them.

Comment: It depend on the architecture to have segmented memory and compiler depends on arch as it targets that architecture. So you have to name an architecture. For x86 you might need to modify the values of the segement registers.

Answer (score 0):

Linux programs have two data sections: ".data" and ".bss". The ".data" is used for variables with initial value (static int x=5), while the ".bss" is used for variables that start with 0 (static int x). Adding data to '.data' will result in space to hold the initial value.

Consider going for the ".bss" section, which will have little impact on object size.